# Node and passport: Should passport.js be in gitignore?

Tags: node.js, git, version-control, passport.js, gitignore

I was building user authentication following this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local). In here the writer has the passport.js file in the config directory, along with the authentication tokens, and database login string. I understand why the database and auth config's should not be public, so normally I would .gitignore the entire config directory. However this passport.js file is code that I would like to have version control on. Is there any reason this file doesn't belong in public version control, and if so how should I go about removing just that content so the logic of the code can be checked in.

#### Passport.JS

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

var User = require('../app/models/user');

var configAuth = require('../config/auth');

module.exports = function(passport){
   passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
      done(null, user.id);
   });

   passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
      User.findById(id,function(err, user){
     done(err, user);
      });
   });

   passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true
      },
      function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done){
     process.nextTick(function(){
        if(!req.user)
        {
           User.findOne({'google.id': profile.id}, function(err, user){
              if(err)
              {
                 return done(err);
              }
              if(user)
              {
                 return done(null, user);
              }
              else
              {
                 var newUser = new User();
                 newUser.account.google_id = profile.id;
                 newUser.account.google_token = token;
                 newUser.account.name = profile.displayName;
                 newUser.account.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                 newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err)
                    {
                       throw err;
                    }
                    return done(null, newUser);
                 });
              }
           });
        }
        else
        {
           var user = req.user;
           user.account.google_id = profile.id;
           user.account.google_token = token;
           user.account.name = profile.displayName;
           user.account.email = profile.emails[0].value;

           user.save(function(err){
              if(err)
              {
                 throw err;
              }
              return done(null, user);
           });
        }
     });
      }
   ));

   passport.use(new TwitterStrategy(
      {
     consumerKey: configAuth.twitterAuth.consumerKey,
     consumerSecret: configAuth.twitterAuth.consumerSecret,
     callbackURL: configAuth.callbackURL,
     passReqToCallback: true
      },
      function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done){
     console.log(token);
     process.nextTick(function(){
        if(!req.user)
        {
           User.findOne({'twitter.id': profile.id }, function(err, user){
              if(err)
              {
                 return done(err);
              }

              if(user)
              {
                 return done(null, user);
              }
              else
              {
                 var newUser = new User();

                 newUser.account.twitter_id = profile.id;
                 newUser.account.twitter_token = token;
                 newUser.account.twitter_username = profile.username;
                 console.log(newUser);

                 newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err)
                    {
                       throw err;
                    }
                    return done(null, newUser);
                 });
              }
           });
        }
        else{
           var user = req.user;

           user.account.twitter_id = profile.id;
           user.account.twitter_token = token;
           user.account.twitter_username = profile.username;
           user.save(function(err){
              if(err)
              {
                 throw err;
              }
              return done(null, user);
           });

        }
     });
      }
   ));

   passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(
      {
     clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
     clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
     callbackURL : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
     passReqToCallback: true,
     profileFields: ["email", "name"],
      },
      function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done){
     process.nextTick(function(){
        if(!req.user)
        {
           User.findOne({'facebook.id' : profile.id}, function(err, user){
              if(err)
              {
                 return done(err);
              }

              if(user)
              {
                 return done(null, user);
              }

              else
              {
                 var newUser = new User();
                 newUser.account.facebook_id = profile.id;
                 newUser.account.facebook_token = token;
                 newUser.account.name =  profile.displayName;
                 newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err)
                    {
                       throw err;
                    }
                    return done(null, newUser);
                 });
              }
           });
        }
        else
        {
           var user = req.user;

           user.account.facebook_id = profile.id;
           user.account.facebook_token = token;
           user.account.name = profile.displayName;
           user.save(function(err){
              if(err)
              {
                 throw err;
              }
              return done(null, user);
           });
        }
     });
      }
   ));

   passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
      {
     usernameField: 'email',
     passwordField: 'password',
     passReqToCallback: true
      },
      function(req, email, password, done){
     process.nextTick(function(){
        User.findOne({'local.email': email}, function(err, user){
           if(err)
           {
              return done(err);
           }
           if(user){
              return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage',' That email is already taken'));
           }
           else
           {
              var newUser = new User();
              newUser.account.email = email;
              newUser.account.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

              newUser.save(function(err){
                 if(err)
                 {
                    throw err;
                 }
                 return done(null, newUser);
              });
           }
        });
     });
   }));

   passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy(
      {
     usernameField: 'email',
     passwordField: 'password',
     passReqToCallback : true
      },
      function(req, email, password, done){
     User.findOne({'local.email': email}, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        {
           return done(err);
        }

        if(!user)
        {
           return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Username not found!'));
        }

        if (!user.validPassword(password))
        {
           return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Incorrect Password'));
        }

        return done(null, user);
     });
      }
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is: keep sensitive data out of version control.

I see nothing sensitive in the file, and therefore it **should** be checked into version control.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if the knowledge of how this file was set up could be used maliciously or not. I figured since the keys were already redacted from this it was no longer sensitive.